# How Load Images From Drop down button Google WebApp script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to load images from the drop-down button generated based on the Google Sheet's Folder ID

**Google Sheet**

[image]

**Out Put**

[image]

What I'm Trying To ACHIEVE is: I want to load the images on the front end display which is in a google drive folder based on the drop-down list on the front end of Web app.

**THE PROBLEM**

I'm unable to add the Folder ID into the `getPictures()` function and also I'm having issues connecting the Folder ID based on the dropdown.

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  
  var pictures = getPictures();
  
  htmlOutput.pictures = pictures;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

function getPictures()
{

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var idURL = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
    var destination_id = '1GNBiddMQZTl3Ti_mKs9CUM541p-yaCnv';  // ID OF GOOGLE DRIVE DIRECTORY;
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
    
    var files = destination.getFiles();
    var file_array = [];
    
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      file_array.push(file.getId());
    }

    return file_array;
}


function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues(); // Retrieve values and send to Javascript
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="dropdown">
     <button onclick="loadpics()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
     <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content"></div>
  </div>

  <h1>Display Pictures</h1>
  <table>
  <?for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { ?>
  <tr><td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<?= pictures[i] ?>" style="width:400px;height:auto;" ></td></tr>
  <? } ?>  
  </table>
  </body>
</html>


<script>
  function loadpics() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      let select = document.createElement("select");
      select.id = "select1";
      select.setAttribute("onchange", "selected()");
      document.getElementById("myDropdown").appendChild(select);
      ar.forEach(function(e, i) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = i;
        option.text = e;
        document.getElementById("select1").appendChild(option);
      });
    }).getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  };

  function selected() {
    const value = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    console.log(value);
  }
</script>
```

COPY OF GOOGLE SHEET - [Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1z3yTpZ-FQ-a3holx3BT5Bg-pvMYmKYvywgANk29VfaU/edit?usp=sharing)

I'm not a coder, Could you please help me to achieve my task. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can refer to this sample code:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput =  HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index');
  var vehicle = getValuesFromSpreadsheet();
  var pictures = getPictures("1"); //show 1st vehicle as default
  htmlOutput.vehicle = vehicle;
  htmlOutput.pictures = pictures;
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

//Get pictures based on the selected option
function getPictures(option)
{
  var row = parseInt(option) + 1;
  Logger.log("option: "+option+" row: "+row);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destination_id = sheet.getRange(row, 2).getDisplayValue();
  var file_array = [];
  Logger.log(destination_id);
  try{
    var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById(destination_id);
    var files = destination.getFiles();
    while (files.hasNext()) 
    {
      var file = files.next();
      file_array.push(file.getId());
    }
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.message);
  }
  Logger.log(file_array.length);
  return file_array;
}


function getValuesFromSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  return sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat(); // Retrieve values and send to Javascript
}
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>

  <div class="dropdown" >
    <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="width:200px;">
      <b>Vehicle Menu: </b> 
      <select id="select1" onchange="selected()">
        <?for(var i = 1; i < vehicle.length; i++) { ?>
        <option value=<?= i ?>><?= vehicle[i] ?></option>
        <? } ?> 
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h1>Display Pictures</h1>
  <div id="defaultPictures">
    <table>
      <?for(var i = 0; i < pictures.length; i++) { ?>
      <tr><td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=<?= pictures[i] ?>" style="width:400px;height:auto;" ></td></tr>
      <? } ?>  
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="displayPictures"></div>
  </body>
</html>


<script>

  function selected() {
    //Hide default pictures
    var defaultDiv = document.getElementById("defaultPictures");
    defaultDiv.style.display = "none";
  
    const value = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    console.log(value);
    
    //Update table from the selected option
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ids) {
    
      //Create a html table string based on the picture ids
      let tblHtml = '<table>';
      //Create table rows from the picture ids
      ids.forEach(id => {
        tblHtml += '<tr><td><img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id='+id+'" style="width:400px;height:auto;" ></td></tr>';
      });
      tblHtml += '</table>';
      //update div to include the table
      console.log(tblHtml);
      document.getElementById("displayPictures").innerHTML = tblHtml;
    }).getPictures(value);

  }
</script>
```

### What it does?

1. I removed the dropdown button. Instead, I updated the dropdown options using `vehicle` variable which was initialized in `doGet()`
2. I created 2 `div` which displays your images. `<div id="defaultPictures">` displays the table of images initialized using `pictures` variable set in `doGet()` while `<div id="displayPictures"></div>` will display the pictures of the selected option in the dropdown menu.
3. I modified `getPictures()` to add `option` argument which is the option value selected in your dropdown menu. Note that the option value is in zero index. ("Prado" value is 1 while "Prado 2" value is 2)
4. When initializing `pictures` variable in your html, I used "Prado" with option value 1 as a default pictures to display.
5. When a dropdown menu is selected, it will call `selected()` in your hmtl. Hide the `defaultPictures` div and create a new table based on the selected option.

### Sample Output:

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you have some issues regarding the solution  so i could update it accordingly.